# how to run first example of Apache Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am trying to run the first example from the oreilly book "Stream Processing with Apache Flink"  and from the flink project.  Each gives different errors

Example from the book gies NoClassDefFound error
Example from flink project gives java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)  but does create a flink job, see screenshot.

Detail below

**Book example**

> java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:scala/runtime/java8/JFunction1$mcVI$sp
>   at io.github.streamingwithflink.chapter1.AverageSensorReadings$$anon$3.createSerializer(AverageSensorReadings.scala:50)

The instructions from the book are:

1. download [flink-1.7.1-bin-scala_2.12.tgz](https://archive.apache.org/dist/flink/flink-1.7.1/flink-1.7.1-bin-scala_2.12.tgz)
2. extract
3. start cluster ./bin/start-cluster.sh
4. open flink's web UI http://localhost:8081

this all works fine

5. Download the [jar file](https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples/blob/master/download/examples-scala.jar) that includes examples in this book
6. run example

```
./bin/flink run \
  -c io.github.streamingwithflink.chapter1.AverageSensorReadings \
  examples-scala.jar
```

It seems that the class is not found from error message at the top of this post.

I put the jar in the same directory I am running the command

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.44.0.9-CA-macosx) (build 1.8.0_242-b20)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.44.0.9-CA-macosx) (build 25.242-b20, mixed mode)
```

I also tried compiling the jar myself with the same error.

`https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples-scala.git`

and

`mvn clean build`

error is the same.

**Flink project tutorial**

running the [SocketWindowWordCount](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/tutorials/local_setup.html)

`./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000`

I get a job but it fails

gives `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

[image]
It is not clear to me what connection is refused.  I tried different ports with no change.

How can I run flink code successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the failing `AverageSensorReadings` example, but it was working on my setup. I'll try look deeper into it tomorrow.

Regarding the `SocketWindowWordCount` example, the error message indicates that the Flink job failed to open a connection to the socket on port 9000. You need to open the socket *before* you start the job. You can do this for example with netcat:

```
nc -l 9000
```

After the job is running, you can send messages by typing and  and these message will be ingested into the Flink job. You can see the stats in the WebUI evolving according to the number of words that your messages consisted of.

Note that netcat closes the socket when you stop the Flink job.

Comment: The SocketWindowWordCount works.  I see that this questions has been answered before.  Just need to follow the instructions.  I am unable to get AverageSensorReadings to work.  I downloaded the jar again with the same result.  I looked in the jar and can see the class there.  Seems that my flink install is functional.  I'lll just continue with the book and hope the next code works.

Comment: I tried git cloning and mvn clean build from https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples-scala with the same error.  Updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Hi @fabian-hueske, thanks for writing your excellent book. I also tried to follow the steps from OP and got the following error `org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program's entry point class 'io.github.streamingwithflink.StreamingJob' was not found in the jar file.`

Comment: I ran `flink run examples-scala.jar` using the examples file from github (linked here https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples/blob/master/download/examples-scala.jar)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the "Stream Processing with Apache Flink" code from IntelliJ.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232605/stream-processing-with-apache-flink-how-to-run-book-code-from-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the "Stream Processing with Apache Flink" `AverageSensorReadings` code on my flink cluster by using sbt.  I have never used sbt before but thought I would try it.  My project is [here](https://github.com/quagly/sbt-flink172)

Note that I moved AverageSensorReading.scala to chapter5 a since that is where the code is explained and changed the package to com.mitzit.

1. use `sbt assembly` to create jar
2. run on flink cluster

```
./bin/flink run \
  -c com.mitzit.chapter5.AverageSensorReadings \
  /path/to/project/sbt-flink172/target/scala-2.11/sbt-flink172-assembly-0.1.jar
```

works fine.  I have no idea why this works and the `mvn` compiled jar does not.